# How to access the view such as imageview and label in SearchBar Reference?

Tags: ios, searchbar, subviews

I am trying to customize the SearchBar using the SearchBar reference as declared bellow

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchRef;
```

Then, i am trying to access the UIImage Reference and UISearchBarTextFieldLabel as shown in picture

[image: This is the picture]

I am printing the reference of the subviews using following code

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.searchRef.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews);
```

but not getting the result as expected. I want the UIImage ref as well as UISearchBarTextFieldLabel. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to the text field, you can cast it as `UITextField` and then access its `leftView` and `rightView` properties. Usually, the `leftView` is the magnifying glass `UIImageView`.

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)self.searchRef.subviews[0].subviews[1];

// Change the search image.
if ([textField.leftView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {

    UIImageView *searchImageView = (UIImageView *)textField.leftView;

    // Do something with the image view here...
}
```

As a side note, it's not recommended to assume that `UISearchBar's` views will always be laid out this way. For example, Apple may decide in future to change the view hierarchy, which could cause your code to fail or crash completely.

If you *must* do this, it would be safer to recursively search each view's subviews until you find what you're looking for, instead of hard-coding array indices.

Comment: What an answer dude. Amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the imageView from searchbar like this than you can reach the uiimage

**Objective-C**

```
UITextField *textFieldInsideSearchBar = [self.searhBar valueForKey:@"searchField"];
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *) textFieldInsideSearchBar.leftView;
```

**Swift 3** and **Swift 4**

```
let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
let imageView = textFieldInsideSearchBar?.leftView as! UIImageView
```